# Is there a way to push key value pairs in google earth engine in a loop that is using the map() function?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am doing a spatiotemporal analysis of LULC on google earth engine. 
For this, I have imported Landsat 5 tier 1 TOA reflectance images and filtered them by my preference. Following this I was able to extract the id values of the features in the filtered image collection, I need to create a dictionary in order to be able to assign the unique names from ID extracted by slicing the ID's and assign a value(id itself) to each pair.

The id obtained of images in an image collection is of the type: LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_148045_19890509 
in this,
key:19890509
value:LT05_148045_19890509

both of which can be obtained from slicing the obtained ID

I have filtered the image collection and tried to create a dictionary as follows but it creates an empty dictionary.

```
// Create a list of image objects.
var imageList = Collection.toList(100);
print('imageList', imageList);

// Extract the ID of each image object.
var dicty = ee.Dictionary({}); //def dict for names
var id_list = imageList.map(function(item) {
    var list_nm = ee.Image(item).id();
    var lst_nm_slice = ee.Image(item).id().slice(-8,-1);
    dicty.lst_nm_slice = list_nm;
    return dicty;
});//end of map function
```

I expect the output of dicty to be a dictionary of key-value pairs with each key value getting assigned dynamically in the aforementioned loop so that I can call the images by using the dictionary key value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to provide an iterable object to `.map()` and you get out an iterable like object with the original length (that function applied to each item). Earth Engine processes the function provided into `.map()` in parallel making it difficult to push values to a single variable in memory within that function. So, a solution to this is to set the ID values that you extract within the function to each image in the collection as a property and then outside of the function get the names and ids of the image into a dictionary. Here is a working code example:

```
// Create an ImageCollection and filter by space and time
var Collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('1990-01-01','1991-01-01')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point([86.5861,34.7304]));

print('LT5 Image Collection', Collection);

// Extract the ID of each image object and set as property
// within for each image in the collection
var Collection = Collection.map(function(img) {
    var img_id = img.id();
    var id_slice = img_id.slice(-8);
    return img.set('id',id_slice);
});//end of map function

// Get the image IDs and names as lists from the collection
var ids = ee.List(Collection.aggregate_array('id'));
var names = ee.List(Collection.aggregate_array('system:index'));

// Build dictionary from each image ID and name
var out_dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(ids,names);
print('Output Dictionary',out_dict);
```